# Have imported spreadsheet from Excel to Sheets but this formula doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have text in three columns and need to know how many times a particular name crops up

`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"d6:d37","I6:I37","n6:n37"}),"peter"))`

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. While Excel and Google Sheets are similar apps, there are meny features that doesn't work the same way. Please add some sample data and the expected result to make it easier for others to better understand what the formula should do and verify that their proposals returns the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `sum()` and `indirect()` seem superfluous here. Use this simpler formula:

`=countif( { D6:D37, I6:I37, N6:N37 }, "peter" )`

Comment: Your formula solved my problem, thank you so much